# Records and field syntax error

Tags: python, file, syntax, field, records

I am new to programming. I am currently taking python in school right now and I ran into a error and I figure it out. I keep getting a syntax error and I am not sure if it is typo on the instructor or myself.

```
def main():
    num_emps=int(input("How many employee records? "))
    empfile=open("employee.txt","w")
    for count in range(1,num_emps+1):
        print("Enter data for employee#",count,sep='')
        name=input("Name: ")
        id_num=input("ID Number: ")
        dept=input("Department: ")
        empfile=write.(name+"\n")
        empfile=write.(id_num+"\n")
        empfile=write.(dept+"\n")
        print()
    empfile.close
    print("Employee records written to disk")

main()
```

I keep getting the error at

```
empfile=write.(name+"\n")
```

or is it supposed to be

```
empfile.write(name+"\n")
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try it ! Plus, to close your file, call `empfile.close()` not `empfile.close`

Comment: I tried still getting the same error. Also thanks for the small typo!

Comment: Put the detailled error you get in your question

Answer (score 0):

Use `empfile.write()` instead of `empfile=write.()`

Answer (score 0):

Corrected and optimized version:

```
def main():

    # indentation was missing in your question:

    num_emps = int(input("How many employee records? "))
    empfile = open("employee.txt","w")

    for count in range(num_emps):  # range from 0 to num_emps-1
        print("Enter data for employee #{}:".format(count))  # use str.format(...)

        name = input("Name: ")
        id_num = input("ID Number: ")
        dept = input("Department: ")

        empfile.write(name + "\n")
        empfile.write(id_num + "\n")
        empfile.write(dept + "\n")
        # alternative using Python 3's print function: 
        # print(name, file=empfile)  # line-break already included

        print()
    empfile.close()  # to call the function, you need brackets () !
    print("Employee records written to disk")

main()
```

Also, there's not really a need to write a `main()` function in your example. You could have put the code directly into the file.
And if you want a proper `main()` function, use this construct to call it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
else:
    print("You tried to import this module, but it should have been run directly!")
```

It is used to determine whether a script was invoked directly or imported by another script.